# Best free online application for making notes containing quantum computing math notation?

Tags: resource-request, matrix-representation, terminology-and-notation

This I hope, is not a trivial question. I am sure many like me struggle while making personal notes online and face difficulty in write linear algebra expressions & Dirac notations to explain Mathematics. Please suggest best free online, quantum computing note making application you people use.

Comment: Not online but just use latex

Comment: Overleaf.com is an online latex editor that's commonly used.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about typesetting not about QC.